# Can't access Ubuntu installed through VMware "please wait for the graphical environment to launch"

Tags: system-installation, vmware

I have Windows 7 and I installed VMware 8.0.3 then I installed Virtual Ubuntu 12.04 through VMware, but when I open it I always get this message:

> VMware is currently being installed on your system. Depending on the version of Ubuntu you may log in below and use the system during installation. otherwise, please wait for the graphical environment to launch

I have been getting this message for about 3 days. What is the solution please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should use newer version of VMWARE which is now available.

Comment: Yes it is available.and it has solved the problem also.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post [Webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu.html)

> install the required dependencies and run the downloaded VMware
>   .bundle file:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
> ```
>
> 32bit:
>
> ```
> chmod +x VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.i386.bundle
> sudo ./VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.i386.bundle
> ```
>
> 64bit:
>
> ```
> chmod +x VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.x86_64.bundle
> sudo ./VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.x86_64.bundle
> ```
>
> Install patch
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install patch
> cd
> wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz
> tar -xvf vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz
> sudo ~/vmware802fixlinux320/patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can sign in and start with `startx` command. I was facing similar issue so I used `startx`. What are the drawbacks of it?

Comment: You may want to post a separate question to ask about the drawbacks of manually invoking `startx`.

Answer (score -2):

I thing it must be a problem due to installation of VMware tool for graphical interface.
So its better to connect the machine to the required server where you can get the VMware tool update. Once that will install you will successfully able to create the machine.

Else you need a bundle of required packages along with iso image if working in a standalone system.